# Alignment of tags in agenda view

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

In agenda view, tags are getting right-alingned at column 120! In org file, they are right-aligned at columnt 77.

What is happening? How do I get agenda view to follow org file setting?

Comment: In general, `org-agenda` and `org` have parallel functions and variables.  For `org-mode`, you have `org-tags-column` to configure.  For `org-agenda-mode`, you have `org-agenda-tags-column` to configure.  The functions follow the same methodology, however, be sure to read the doc-string of each variable and function to see what differences exist.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks. That works. And thanks for being patient with such basic questions. The documentation is exhaustive, I agree. But there are missing pieces at times. For instance, when I try customizing emacs, it does not show `org-agenda-tags-column` variable. Am I missing on something?

Comment: `M-x eval-expression RET (require 'org-agenda) RET` and then `M-x describe-variable`.  I don't know about the state of the art version of `org-mode`, but previous versions included in the default Emacs distribution did not load the `org-agenda` library by default.

Comment: @lawlist Will you please add your comment as an answer? I will then accept it. Will be useful if someone faces the same issue